# Could not transfer artifact (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven

I am new to Maven and trying to setup my first project in Maven but receiving the below error message when I am doing " Run as -> Maven install " in Eclipse. Below is my settings.xml and pom.xml

Settings.xml

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <localRepository>C:\Users\Iam\.m2\repository</localRepository>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mytest</groupId> 
  <artifactId>MySpringBootMaven</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


<build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
                <configuration>
                    <warnName>Test.war</warnName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Error message:

```
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.5.11.RELEASE
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.5.11.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.5.11.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

How to resolve the Received fatal alert: protocol_version ? My java version is 1.7 and maven version is 3.3.3

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Sonatype [no longer supports TLSv1.1 and below](https://central.sonatype.org/articles/2018/May/04/discontinued-support-for-tlsv11-and-below/) (effective, June 18th, 2018). My guess is that you are using TLSv1.1 protocol or below.

The documentation I listed gives you 4 options:

1. Upgrade your Java runtime, for example with OpenJDK builds or Oracle paying support
2. Configure your Java runtime to enable TLS 1.2 by adding -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
3. Use a repository manager that uses a Java version supporting TLS 1.2
4. Revert back to http until you can acheive one of the above remediation steps.

I fixed it myself by just using -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 as a VM argument.

Comment: Cool...Thanks...I have updated my java version to 8 and the problem is now solved...

Comment: Thanks for reminding about Java8. On my mac I have both Java7 and Java8, and this is why I got the maven error. The error messages are very misleading!

Comment: Another solution would be to set "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2" to "MAVEN_OPTS" environment variable so that maven can pass this jvm argument to the underlying Java7 runtime which is used to build your application.

Comment: Can someone suggest how to configure same setting in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 17):

For a permanent solution(mostly required in Java 7) - in you build directory(where you do the `mvn` command from) add directory:

`.mvn` (in cmd `mkdir .mvn`)

and in it create file

`jvm.config`

and in put the following line:

`-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Comment: This worked for me when I ran Maven from the build directory.

Comment: If the above tip does not work, just add the option -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 to the mvn command like this: mvn install -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: Above solution is the one that i was looking for and it worked great :)

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution is to configure your JVM runtime arguments. On eclipse, you can do it as following :

go to  windows>preferences>java>installed JREs
click on the Intalled JRE/JDK you are using for your project

click on "edit"  on le right,
and add  `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` in the Default VM arguments Input field.

see the screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

The Package you are trying to install **doesn't support TLS1.1** and you might be by default using TLS 1.1. Configure your Java runtime to enable TLS 1.2 by adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` to your Maven Build command would solve the problem.

For Example: `mvn clean install -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Comment: It solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had upgraded from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8 and got the same error.
To resolve this error, I checked the mvn version using `mvn -version` and found that JAVA_HOME was still using the Java 1.7. I changed the JAVA_HOME in the environment variable to point to Java 1.8 jre in JDK

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I set my **settings.xml** file in the .m2 directory just as the one here: https://github.com/alipay/sofa-rpc/pull/190/files

Then exec `mvn install` and all dependencies started to download. I haven't had a settings.xml file before and I am not using any proxy. 
Hope it helps somebody.

PD. I have jdk 1.7 and Maven 3.3.9

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error in **SpringToolSuit** by adding `settings.xml` file in `.m2` folder which is located in Users folder of `C` drive and by updating Project by
right click on `pom.xml -> Maeven -> Update Project`.

Make sure you select Force update of `snapshots/releases`.

Answer (score 0):

It needs both : Configuring the JVM runtime arguments as well as having a settings.xml, after I did both it worked. Updating only the JVM runtime argument did not help.

Comment: What did you add to your settings.xml to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the automatic update of maven dependencies were disabled in eclipse.

Solution:
Go to 
Windows->Preferences->Maven
and uncheck the check box

"**Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories**"

Then update the project
Right click on project->maven->update project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I tried most of the answers here but still did not work. My issue was Proxy settings on my IDE. So it is also important to remember to check proxy settings. File > Settings > System Settings > HTTP Proxy - Select Auto-Detect proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

On my new laptop (Win10) I have downgraded maven 3.8.7->3.6.3 and jdk 19->1.8

Maven 3.8.7 is blocking a lot of old repositories, one sometimes does need.