# STS on ubuntu: Non-resolvable parent POM Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE

Tags: maven, ubuntu, spring-boot, pom.xml

I am trying to work on ubuntu and I face a problem with STS that I have just installed.
This is a toy project and I do not have any proxies as I am using my home network  and the internet seem to be working just fine. 
I think the problem is ubuntu related as I have installed the same version of STS on my windows computer and it has no problems at all with my project.

I have tried to search on Internet but none of the solutions helped and I could not find any ubuntu specific solutions. My POM is just:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.globomatics</groupId>
<artifactId>bike</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>bike</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the error is:

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.globomatics:bike:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM  pom.xml /bike   line 14 Maven pom Loading Problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to update you Java version to a recent Java 8 or more recent.

This is because connections to Maven Central now require TLS 1.2 which is not the default in earlier versions of Java which would explain why Maven cannot download your parent pom.

See [Could not transfer artifact (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946420/could-not-transfer-artifact-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-received-fat) for details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I have tried it with Java 11 first, when it didn't work 
 I read somewhere that STS might not be working with Java 11 yet, so I switched to Java 8 but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Sorry to hear that... Could you try from the command line with Java 8 and Maven ? Also are you sure STS/Eclipse use Java8 themselves (check in help --> about (or something similar))

Answer (score 0):

The problem has just been solved by itself when I tried to get Gradle plug-in from Marketplace.

Somehow Internet connection in my STS was not fully activated and by installing the plug-in I got it activated and the maven could download dependencies in pom.