# Failed to execute goal errors when running mvn install:install-file

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I'm trying to add a JAR to my local repository. This process worked fine at home, but on another machine it's throwing errors and I don't really know what the issue is. I've tried googling some of the errors to no joy.

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:/Users/yqb18196/Documents/ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< com.websystique.springmvc:Budget >------------------
[INFO] Building Budget 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ Budget ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.5/plexus-utils-3.0.5.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-digest/1.0/plexus-digest-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.729 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-19T14:05:24Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project Budget: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:3.0.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I don't seem to have these mentioned plugins in my pom.xml file, but then I suppose they might be dependencies of dependencies(?)

I've then tried to run `mvn clean install` as some posts suggest, but then I get the following failure:

```
$ mvn clean install
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.298 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-19T15:08:06Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project Budget: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]
```

Anything that I could do to resolve this, or figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: According to this site - http://amibehindaproxy.com/ - I'm not.

Comment: Could this be the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946420/could-not-transfer-artifact-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-received-fat? Which Java Version is running on the other machine?

Comment: That's it, well spotted. Yeh I updated the protocol version and it worked. Actually, it seems to run OK now without adding `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 install`, I'm not sure if it's saved that version now or whether I'll have a similar issue when I need to retrieve new dependencies. Least I know the issue now anyway, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not transfer artifact (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol\_version -> \[Help 1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946420/could-not-transfer-artifact-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-received-fat)