# Getting Error while trying to create Spring boot Netflix eureka server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, server, netflix-eureka, sts

I am getting below error when i try to add maven dependency in pom.xml for eureka server.

********Maven dependency ***********

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

*****Error*****

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:pom:2.11.3 from https://repo.spring.io/milestone was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-milestones has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:pom:2.11.3 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): The operation was cancelled.
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946420/could-not-transfer-artifact-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-received-fat Give this link a read.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a versions' compatibility issue. Check out the corresponding versions here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: I am adding version:  spring boot version: 2.4.0  ,  java.version : 11, spring-cloud.version: 2020.0.0-M5.  I am getting error on adding dependency for  eureka server "spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server"

Comment: Now I think it's not related to Spring Cloud, rather a dependency issue. `mvn clean install -U` will update your dependencies, ignoring the cache.