# Maven not able to resolve the xerces dependency but resolving others

Tags: java, maven

I have the following pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>xml-parsing</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>xml-parsing</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.xerces</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

For some reason, maven is unable to find the Xerces dependency. Running the install method inside Lifecycle and the command mvn clean install shows the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project xml-parsing: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:xml-parsing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.xerces:org.apache.xerces:jar:2.12.2, org.apache.xerces:xml-apis:jar:2.11.0-20110622: Could not find artifact org.apache.xerces:org.apache.xerces:jar:2.12.2 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

Not sure why this could be the case, probably I am missing something in the pom.xml

**Things I tried:**
I added another dependency of the groupId org.apache.xerces -> unresolved
Then I added apache-commons dependency and this got resolved.
Not sure what could be the reason for this.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946420/could-not-transfer-artifact-https-repo-maven-apache-org-maven2-received-fat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with "Xerces hell" in Java/Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven)

Comment: @Michael It's not wrong, it does exist here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xerces/org.apache.xerces/2.12.2

Comment: @Michael  Nice, I see that the Usage and Ranking is too low.

Comment: @Michael I wanted to use the apache xerces to pass a .rnc file and set a schema like: ` SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        Schema schema = 
        factory.setSchema();`  Could you guide how should I construct the Schema here

Comment: @Michael you can post your answer. I will mark it as a solution

Comment: @pensee I haven't used Xerces in a long time, so I can't help with that one. I've found ChatGPT quite good for those kind of questions personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group ID and artifact ID seem wrong.

There is a version of Xerces hosted under those IDs, but it's within an obscure repository called ["Clazzes"](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/clazzes-maven) which only hosts a single version of it: 2.12.2. This a strong clue that this isn't the source of truth, along with the fact that the number of usages is very low.

You *could* rely on that, but it would require adding a `<repository>` definition to Maven, and there's no guarantee that future version of Xerces will be uploaded there.

The "real" Xerces should use these coordinates, which I found just by [searching for "Xerces" on mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=xerces)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version><!-- change me, e.g. to 2.12.2--></version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that does not work is, that the Artifacts are simply not in the default repository.
If you follow the link https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and search for them you won't find them --> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/
You can always check Maven Repository Sites like https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xerces/org.apache.xerces to check for which version of an Artifact is available and where.
For example your org.apache.xerces:org.apache.xerces:jar:2.12.2 is available only in the Clazzes repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xerces/org.apache.xerces?repo=clazzes-maven

Apache-commons probably has the dependency bundled (you could check the maven Repository for that).

So if you don't want the apache-commons and just the xerces dependencies, then you have to add the repository in the pom file --> https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html

UPDATE:
This is what it could look like in the pom file at the end:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <!-- For Xerces stuff -->
      <id>clazzes</id>
      <name>Clazzes Repository</name>
      <url>https://maven.clazzes.org/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Comment: I am not sure what id and URL to add in repository tag

Comment: @pensee FYI, though not what you want to do in this case, if you click on the repository on that website, it will list the URL (https://mvnrepository.com/repos/clazzes-maven) -> `https://maven.clazzes.org/`. Repo ID in Maven is mostly arbitrary, so in this case "clazzes" would do.